# How to add instances of a class to a 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem where I need to create a grid of a certain size that can be user defined otherwise it defaults to 7. Each cell on the grid can itself contain items so in a way this is a 3D ArrayList. What I decided to do was create a Grid class which would be a 2D ArrayList and then have a separate class called Cell which was just an ArrayList. So, the goal is to have a 2D ArrayList of size nxn which would have a n^2 instances of the Cell class. However, I am having trouble iterating through the ArrayList that I made and am starting to think that I made the 2D ArrayList wrong to begin with. Essentially what I am trying to get help with is how to instantiate and fill the 2D ArrayList with all the instances of Cell.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Cell {
    private ArrayList contents = new ArrayList();
}

class Grid {

    public ArrayList<ArrayList> grid = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

    public Grid () {
        for (Object array : this.grid){
            ArrayList new_array = (ArrayList) array;
            for (int i=0; i<7;i++){
                this.grid.add(new Cell());
            }
        }
    }

    public Grid (int size) {
        for (Object array : this.grid){
            ArrayList new_array = (ArrayList) array;
            for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
                this.grid.add(new Cell());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't initialized the grid.
If you want to make 2D grid, you should make rows before add items to row, and you should specify the type of inner arraylist.

```
class Cell {
    private ArrayList contents = new ArrayList();
}

class Grid {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>> grid = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Cell>>();

    //Generate 7 by 7 grid
    public Grid() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            ArrayList<Cell> innerList = new ArrayList<Cell>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                innerList.add(new Cell());
            }
            grid.add(innerList);
        }
    }

    //Generate size by size grid
    public Grid(int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ArrayList<Cell> innerList = new ArrayList<Cell>();
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                innerList.add(new Cell());
            }
            grid.add(innerList);
        }
    }

}
```